# Prisma: Find existing where list contain any of given list incorrect

Tags: typescript, postgresql, next.js, prisma

In my Prisma model I got a property to store a list of phone numbers as follows
`phones String[] @unique`

When calling my api with a model which can contain one or more phone numbers, I want to find any existing record where any phone match any of the the given phone numbers.

I do this with the code below

The reason I think this is wrong, is sometimes I get a unique constraint error when a records is created (so a record with that phone already exists, so should have called my update method meaing my query logic must be wrong)

```
  const body = await request.json();
  const records = await prisma.person.findMany({
    where: {
      phones: {
        hasSome: body.phones,
      },
    },
  });

  if (records.length > 0) {
    const updated = await UpdatePerson(records[0], body); 
    return NextResponse.json(false, {
      status: 200,
    });
  } else {
    const created = await CreatePerson(body); 
    return NextResponse.json(false, {
      status: 200,
    });
  }
}
```

For completeness sake (and being a prisma noob, any advice might be welcome) below is the create and edit methods

```
async function CreatePerson(data: Person) {
  try {
    const result = await prisma.person.create({
      data,
    });
    return result;
  } catch (error) { 
    throw new Error("Failed to create person");
  }
}
```

```
async function UpdatePerson(
  existing: Person,
  data: Person,
) {
  try {

    const updatedPerson = await prisma.person.update({
      where: {
        id: existing.id,
      },
      data: {
        ....
        phones: addMissingItems(existing.phones, data.phones),
        email: existing.email ? existing.email : data.email ? data.email : null,
```

and a helper method to join 2 string arrays

```
export function addMissingItems(
  firstArray: string[],
  secondArray: string[],
): string[] {
  // Create a copy of the second array to avoid modifying the original array
  const resultArray = secondArray.slice();

  // Loop through items in the first array
  for (const item of firstArray) {
    // Check if the item is not in the second array
    if (!resultArray.includes(item)) {
      // Add the item to the result array
      resultArray.push(item);
    }
  }

  return resultArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was actually unrelated to above but rather with historical data where there was 2 or more records, which the code I posted expected to be a single record.

I modified it to merge historical data whenever one pass in an array of phones and mulitple records exists for those records.